# Изменения списка на числа в Python 3

Tags: python, строки, числа, преобразование-типов

Написал программу для выполнения задачи.
Код написал правильно, но в условии требуют вывод данных через числа ,а не через строки.
Подскажите пожалуйста как в конце кода преобразовать переменную d в числа.
Вот код:

```
a.sort()
d = []
b = 0
c = 1
for i in a[:-1]:
    if a[b] == a[c] and a[c] not in d:
        d += a[c]
    b += 1
    c += 1 
При попытке преобразовать через: 
print(int(f) for f in d)
Выдает ошибку:
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x000001DE2C2947C8>#что это значит?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решается ваш вопрос так - добавлением квадратных скобок:

```
print([int(f) for f in d])
```

**Пояснение:**

Функция `print` печатает то, что ей передают на вход. В вашем случае такая форма записи:

```
print(int(f) for f in d)
```

Означает, что вы передаёте на вход функции `print` *генератор*, получившийся в результате работы *списочного генератора*. Этот списочный генератор можно записать ещё так:

```
(int(f) for f in d)
```

Функция `print` вам и сообщает, что получила на вход `generator object`.

А вот если передать функции `print` *списочное сокращение* (результатом работы которого которого является *список*), как в моём варианте кода, то `print` знает, что с делать со списком - он успешно напечатает все его элементы.

Answer (score 1):

ну выведите так:

```
print(*map(int, d))
```